# How can I call an internal sip phone using a server with freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch

I want to make an internal call from a server with freeswitch to a sip phone that's registered and connected and has the extension of 1000

I'm fairly sure I use originate sofia and I've been trying several combinations with no result.
The sort of thing I've been trying is

```
 originate sofia/internal/1000@[my IP address] &park{}
```

And I get the result

> -ERR NO_USER_RESPONSE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently outside of my lab, but I believe you can use "user/1000" as the first destination.  Also "sofia/internal/1000" should probably work.